# error - Runtime error 9 "subscript out of range"

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

i have an error with the code :

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'

Dim a As String

 a = "=*" & CStr(Range("a2").Value) & "*"

   With Sheet1.ListObjects("Table2")
        If Not .DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then
            .DataBodyRange.Delete
        End If
    End With


    If IsEmpty(Range("a2")) = False Then

        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=a, Operator:=xlAnd

    Else: End If
```

I didn't understand why i get an error with a dynamic criteria. Can anyone help or suggest something ? (error is on the line starts with

> ActiveSheet.ListObjects

thanks

Comment: Seems like there's no ListObject named "Table1" in the active sheet. Perhaps the active sheet is not the correct one? Try referring to a sheet name, index, or preferably a sheet's code name. [This page explains it](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/workbook-worksheet-object.html)

Comment: @TimStack correct, i converted table to list and forgot it. Thanks. 

i cannot filter numbers in a table by "contains" any number in it, any idea ?